# Set "visibleEdit" and "visibleDelete" values of UI5 sap.m.UploadCollectionItem in JS code

Tags: sapui5

I'm working with [`sap.m.UploadCollection`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.UploadCollection).
Now I want to be able to change the values of `enableEdit`, `enableDelete`, `visibleEdit`, `visibleDelete` in runtime per file, according to the values coming from the backend, and not only statically in [`sap.m.UploadCollectionItem`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.UploadCollectionItem#constructor) via the XML-template.

I've tried something like that:

```js
oController.getModel("files").setProperty("/visibleEdit", false)
```

but it seems to be a wrong approach.

How can I set a desired value of `visibleEdit` per file with JS (runtime)?

The view snippet with the `UploadCollection` component:

```xml
<UploadCollection
    id="UploadCollection"
    maximumFilenameLength="255"
    maximumFileSize="10"
    multiple="false"
    showSeparators="All"
    change="onFileChanged"
    noDataText="{texte>/FAM081}"
    fileDeleted="onFileDelete"
    filenameLengthExceed="onFilenameLengthExceed"
    fileRenamed="onFileChange"
    fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed"
    selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
    typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch"
    uploadComplete="onUploadComplete"
    uploadButtonInvisible="{=${screen_model>/KomItemAdd}!==true}"
    beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts"
    uploadTerminated="onUploadTerminated"
    items="{path : 'files>/', templateShareable : 'true'}"
    numberOfAttachmentsText="Uploaded (8)"
    mode="SingleSelectMaster"
    uploadUrl="%MY_UPLOAD_URL%">
    <toolbar>
        <OverflowToolbar id="myId">
            <ToolbarSpacer />
            <UploadCollectionToolbarPlaceholder></UploadCollectionToolbarPlaceholder>
        </OverflowToolbar>
    </toolbar>
    <items>
        <UploadCollectionItem
            documentId="{files>documentId}"
            fileName="{files>fileName}"
            mimeType="{files>mimeType}"
            thumbnailUrl="{files>thumbnailUrl}"
            url="{files>url}"

            visible="{= ${files>text}!==''}"

            enableEdit="{=${files>userID}===${userdata>/UserId}}"
            enableDelete="{=${files>userID}===${userdata>/UserId}}"

            visibleDelete="{=${files>userID}===${userdata>/UserId} &amp;&amp; ${screen_model>/KomItemAdd}===true}"
            visibleEdit=  "{=${files>userID}===${userdata>/UserId} &amp;&amp; ${screen_model>/KomItemAdd}===true}"

            attributes="{path : 'files>attributes', templateShareable : 'true'}"
            statuses="{path : 'files>statuses', templateShareable : 'true'}"
            selected="{selected}">
    
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute title="{files>title}"
                text="{files>text}"
                active="{files>active}"
                press="onAttributePress"/>
            </attributes>
    
            <statuses>
                <ObjectStatus title="{files>title}"
                    text="{files>text}"
                    state="{files>state}"
                    icon="{files>icon}"
                    iconDensityAware="{files>iconDensityAware}"
                    textDirection="{files>textDirection}"/>
            </statuses>
        </UploadCollectionItem>
    </items>
</UploadCollection>
```

In this snippet the value of `enableEdit`, `enableDelete`, `visibleEdit`, `visibleDelete` are hardcoded, based on a legacy logic.

Now, I'm required to add an additional condition regarding `enableEdit`, `enableDelete`, `visibleEdit`, `visibleDelete`. Ideally, I want to implement this change in the controller to have more flexibility and more control over this logic.

Comment: Can you provide the view snippet? Without that it's hard to tell. In any case by default there is no `getModel` method in the controller class. Or you have a kind of BaseController or you do a `controller.getView().getModel`. But we need to understand how the UploadCollection aggregation binging was defined.

Comment: @fabiopagoti, sorry for the delay with the response, I've added a code-snippet for the view. Hope, it brings more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `enableEdit`, `enableDelete`, `visibleEdit`, `visibleDelete` property value, not updating the value of json model.

Please refer UI5 methods:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollectionItem%23methods/setEnableEdit